# After edit event in JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, listener

I have a JTable with a column called ID, I wish to edit the cell and then to leave this, is complete information of the person in the other columns.
How do I do this in swing of java 1.6?
In other words is like the event after_edit_cell vb

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Update the table's `TableModel`. See also [*How to Use Tables*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html).

Answer (score -1):

I'm not a pro on this. Hope this help.

Did you try to override the `valueChanged()` method of your model?

When you leave the cell, the `valueChanged()` method is called.  You can do whatever you want in it before calling the `super.valueChanged()` method.

Comment: welcome to the forum :-) But no, there is no valueChanged in any "model" relevant to table editing. Especially as a non-pro you should a) be precise about what "model" class exactly you are talking b) check the api doc and/or a basic tutorial example of that class